# heightForRowAtIndexPath for longer NSStrings

Tags: iphone, uitableview, nsstring

I have a `UITableView` (Grouped!) and need to calculate the height of two styles of cells: `UITableViewCellStyleDefault` and `UITableViewCellStyleValue2`.

**This is how I do it for `UITableViewCellStyleDefault`:**

```
CGSize  textSize = {300.f, 200000.0f};
CGSize  size = [myTextString1 sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f] constrainedToSize:textSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
size.height += 30.0f;
result = MAX(size.height, 44.0f);
```

**And for `UITableViewCellStyleValue2`:**

```
CGSize  textSize = {207.f, 200000.0f};
CGSize  size = [myTextString2 sizeWithFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f] constrainedToSize:textSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
size.height += 30.0f;
result = MAX(size.height, 44.0f);
```

My issue it that they return incorrect heights and I think it's the `textSize` where I use incorrect numbers. With long texts, the bottom part gets cut short (usually just a line with a few words), and for both CellStyles they have weird spacing above and below the text in the cell.

For `UITableViewCellStyleValue2` I got the width size (`207.0f`) from making the text.backgroundColor red and then just calculating the size of the box. `300.0f` width for `UITableViewCellStyleDefault` is how big the cell is with `UITableViewStyleGrouped`.

Does anyone know which values I need to use to properly calculate the size of an `NSString` and thereby get appropriate height for my cells?

**Thanks**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is the code I am using for this.  It works like a charm for one type of cell.  It may have some useful parts for your application.

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *) indexPath {
AppAppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
NSString *Text = ([[appDelegate.myTextSectionsDelegateDict objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectForKey:@"Text"]);

    UIFont *cellFont = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17.0];
    CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(280.0f, MAXFLOAT);
    CGSize labelSize = [Text sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    return labelSize.height + 15;}
```

Comment: Thanks. I ended up doing something alone with same lines. I found out I was having issues with the Value2 cells, because I assumed they were fontSize 14, while they're actually 15.

For your code, you might want to add:

result = MAX(labelsize.height + 15, 44.0f);

Just in case if the cell is ever empty or less then 2 lines it'll return it with a minimum row height of 44.0f, which is the normal. If there's just one line it'll make it smaller than 44.0f.

Answer (score 2):

When you create your cell, are you using the same font as the one you use to measure?

I used the tutorial on [this page](http://www.raddonline.com/blogs/geek-journal/iphone-sdk-resizing-a-uitableviewcell-to-hold-variable-amounts-of-text/) and everything worked for me. It might be useful to you too:

Comment: Yes, I use the same font size and type (bold/not bold). I'll have a look at the link and see if that solves it and let you know.

Comment: I found out I wasn't using the correct font! I found out I was having issues with the Value2 cells, because I assumed they were fontSize 14, while they're actually 15. The other cell style I needed to play around with the amount of height it adds to the text height.

Answer (score 2):

It seeems you've figured out that you were using the wrong text size. You might want to just use the `font` and `lineBreakMode` properties of the label to avoid this problem in the future, especially if you change them in the cell at a later time. Also, for readability's sake, I would avoid adding to the height before returning a number. Instead I'd try something like this:

```
CGSize textSize = CGSizeMake( 300.0, 1979 );
CGSize size = [ myTextString1 sizeWithFont:[[ cell textLabel ] font ]
                         constrainedToSize:textSize
                             lineBreakMode:[[ cell textLabel ] lineBreakMode ]];

result = MAX( size.height + 30, 44.0f );
```

I used 1979 because according to the documentation, one should not return values larger than 2009.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I set some constants for the font sizes, so if I change it for the cell, it'll update everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to calculate the height properly for cellvalue2 you should use:
`[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0f]` and as linebreakmode: `NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail`

If you don't use bold, the text will fill correctly but you will lose the correct vertical padding.

The rest of your calculation are correct.

Answer (score 0):

When is working for me is to compute the constraintSize based on the width of the table view:

```
CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(tableView.frame.size.width * 0.6, 2009);
CGSize labelSize = [cellText sizeWithFont:cellFont constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this:

```
- (CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

CGFloat result = 10.0f;
if(indexPath.section == 1) // here i compare the sections
{
    result = 400.0f;
}
return result;
}
```

Return the values based on the sections you have. This will give you custom row heights.