# Let user change font size for UITableView content

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uitableview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [heightForRowAtIndexPath for longer NSStrings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1160765/heightforrowatindexpath-for-longer-nsstrings)

I making an iphone app where the UITableView gets populated with Text form Core Data.

I want to give the user an option to set the font size for the text in the cell. When the font size will be increased the cell hight will have to increase as well.

What possible options do i have to implement this ?

Answer (score 0):

maybe this will help you:
[autoresizingeditabletableviewcell](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/autoresizingeditabletableviewcell)

Comment: na. i need to let the user adjust the font size.